# get the sum of two checkbox on check

Tags: javascript

hy, my is that it doesn't work. i want on check to visualize the sum between the selected checkbox. for example if i check only the first, it shows me a value, for the other one another value; if i check both, the sum of the values.

thanks for the help

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkvalnotset1" value="45" onClick="sumvalnotset()"> this is a checkbox that gain value when checked
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkvalnotset2" value="20" onClick="sumvalnotset()"> this is a checkbox that gain value when checked
<p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
<script>
function setvalue(x){
 if(x.checked){
  x.value = x.defaultValue;
 } else {
  x.classList.value = 0;
 }
 return x.value;
}
var a = setvalue(document.getElementById("checkvalnotset1"));
var b = setvalue(document.getElementById("checkvalnotset2"));
var p = document.getElementById("sumvalnotset");

function sumvalnotset(){
p.innerHTML = "the value is " + +a + +b
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: You're calling your set function on your two boxes and changing the value/displaying it in `p`, but then never doing it again. You need to look at events. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_events.htm

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say; I'v also tryed to put p.innerHTML ecc... inside a functon, and assign that function, using onClick, at the input elements, but even in this case didn't work..

Comment: I've changed the first post, can anyone help me? it doesn't still work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sum = 0;

function sumvalnotset(event) {
  if(event.checked) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(event.value);
  } else {
    sum = sum > 0 ? sum - parseInt(event.value) : sum;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('sumvalnotset').innerText = 'the value is: '+ sum;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkvalnotset1" value="45" onClick="sumvalnotset(this)" onchange=""> this is a checkbox that gain value when checked
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkvalnotset2" value="20" onClick="sumvalnotset(this)"> this is a checkbox that gain value when checked
<p id="sumvalnotset">
   the value is: 0
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your event handler has follows:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkvalnotset1" value="45" onClick="sumvalnotset()"> this is a checkbox that gain value when checked
<input type="checkbox" id="checkvalnotset2" value="20" onClick="sumvalnotset()"> this is a checkbox that gain value when checked
<p id="sumvalnotset">the value is 0</p>
<script>
function sumvalnotset() {
  var chk1 = document.getElementById("checkvalnotset1");
  var chk2 = document.getElementById("checkvalnotset2");
  var val1 = chk1.checked ? Number(chk1.value):0;
  var val2 = chk2.checked ? Number(chk2.value):0;
  var p = document.getElementById("sumvalnotset");
  p.innerHTML = "the value is " + (val1 + val2);
}
</script>
</div>
```